# Plupload file upload not working in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, plupload

I have a webiste where user's can upload their images. I am struck at IE10 not bringing file upload folder. I am using Plupload jquery files with latest version(v1.5.6). It works very well with Firefix, Opera, Chrome and IE9 but not IE10.

Clicking on 'Upload' button does nothing.

Can someone please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with plupload 1.5.x in IE10: the browse button would stop working if lines were added or removed above it on the page. This ultimately turned out to be because of the way the plupload html4 implementation works on some platforms: it actually places a hidden component over the browse button, and when my page changes happened, the hidden component was still at the old pixel position, and no longer over the button.

To work around this, I added a `mouseover` handler to the browse button that calls `.refresh()` on the plupload `Uploader` object; this re-positions the hidden component to the new position of the browse button, in time for the user to click it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that under very specific conditions I got plupload to not work.

An easy way to test if you are in the same situation I was in, then using the html5 runtime won't work (as you describe) but using the flash runtime instead will work. Test it out, and if that's the case, look into [this issue](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/788).